# How to pass a value from one UIViewController from another?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

I have two `UIViewController`: "MenuViewController" and "DetailViewController".

I'm trying to set DetailViewController's label text as a `NSString` in the MenuViewController, but doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that doesn't work, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple, add `@property (retain) NSString* string;` in the `DetailedViewController` and before navigate to it set this property like this

```
DetailedViewController *dvc = [[DetailedViewController alloc] init];
[dvc setString:@"someString"];
[self pushViewController:dvc]
```

in DetailedViewController in `ViewDidLoad` set the label:

```
[[self label] setText:[self string]];
```

Comment: Couple of points, add a 'nonatomic' keyword along side retain. Also, if this is ARC, use 'strong' instead of 'retain'.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work...